# Implement interface in POJO if contains field

Tags: java, interface, code-generation, jooq

I generate java classes with jOOQ. And I want to make POJOs implement an interface which contains only getters for fields. Obviously, I need this interface only in POJOs with such fields.
I need check class or table for field and, if field extists, implement interface in pojo.

Overriding `getJavaClassImplements` in `DefaultGeneratorStrategy` does not help because it adds the interface for all classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Configurative generator strategy

You seem to be implementing a [programmatic generator strategy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/), just to let you know that there's also an option of a [configurative strategy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/), which could look like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <strategy>
      <matchers>
        <tables>
          <table>
            <expression>MY_TABLE</expression>
            <pojoImplements>com.example.MyOptionalCustomInterface</pojoImplements>
          </table>
        </tables>
        ...
```

[Please refer to the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/) for more details. In order to apply this only to tables containing certain fields, just update the regular expression in `<expression>` to match those tables.

```xml
<expression>MY_TABLE1|MY_TABLE2</expression>
```

This expression has to be updated to be in sync with the schema, of course.

### Programmatic genenerator strategy

Just like with the configurative strategy, you'll have to limit yourself to applying your logic only to generated POJOs. For this, notice the remark in the [manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/):

```java
/**
 * ...
 * Beware that most methods also receive a "Mode" object, to tell you whether a
 * TableDefinition is being rendered as a Table, Record, POJO, etc. Depending on
 * that information, you can add a suffix only for TableRecords, not for Tables
 * ...
 */
```

So, you'll have to do something like this:

```java
@Override
public List<String> getJavaClassImplements(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    if (mode == Mode.POJO)
        return Arrays.asList("com.example.MyOptionalCustomInterface");
    else
        return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

If you want to make sure that this inteface is only added to tables that match certain conditions, do this, instead:

```java
@Override
public List<String> getJavaClassImplements(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    if (mode == Mode.POJO
            && definition instanceof TableDefinition t
            && t.getColumns().stream().anyMatch(c -> conditionHere(c)))
        return Arrays.asList("com.example.MyOptionalCustomInterface");
    else
        return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Both strategies does not allow add interface FOR ANY CLASS WHICH CONTAINS some field and getter for him. For example, I want implement interface with method Integer getId().
I need check class or table for field and, if field extists, implement interface.

Comment: @tolfel: Of course you can do that. I've updated my answer showing how to do this for both cases